# How do you manage the schedule data structure in database?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do you manage the schedule in database??

I have application which owner register the schedule data and user can register the schedule for  the unit of 30minuts. (like meeting room booking service)

In this case.

How do you store the data in database??

For example owner input like this

```
8/23 14:30-17:00
8/27 12:00-14:00
```

idea1) separate every schedule into 30 min (many rows)

```
8/23 14:30-15:00
8/23 15:00-15:30
8/24 15:30-16:00
.
.
8/27 13:30-14:00
```

idea2)

separate into days (2 rows)

```
8/23 14:30-17:00
8/27 12:00-14:00
```

idea3)

Make table row for each registration.

[idea1] is very easy to understand which time slot is booked or not.
and if you want to cancel like this

```
cancel 8/23 15:30-16:00
```

it’s easy to handle.

However if you want to put like this,
'repeat every thursday'
It’s impossible .

[idea3]It can realize 'repeat every thursday' 
However it is very complex to comprehend the booking or canceling.

[idea2] is between two.

How do you store the schedule data in database??

How google stores for google calendar??

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a table where each row is one 'registration'. In the row, you store the start date/time and the end date/time and of course any other information on the 'registration'. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `registration` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime NOT NULL,
  `comment` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This way, you can find for any time whether some registration is there with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `registration`
WHERE `start` <= '2015-08-18 14:00:00'
AND `end` >= '2015-08-18 14:00:00'
```

Cancelling a registration is easy once you have the `id` of it:

```
DELETE FROM `registration` WHERE `id` = 3
```

An important advantage of storing the dates and times instead of using fixed time slots, is that you can easily define slots with higher precision that 30 minutes.

How Google stores their data, is of course their trade secret...